# Two processes writing on the same file

Tags: c, fork, fwrite

I know this is recipe for disaster. And I actually made it work using shared variables.

But it's homework, and teacher definitely wants us to put many processes writing to the same file using different file pointers. I've been trying all day with little success, but I just can't find why this fails.

I have approached the problem in the folowing way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status;
    int process_count = 0;

    do
    {
        int from = (n / np) * (process_count) + 1;
        int to = (n / np) * (process_count + 1);

        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            FILE *aux;
            aux = fopen("./parciais.txt", "w");
            fseek(aux, sizeof(int) * process_count, SEEK_SET);

            int sum = 0;
            int i = from;
            while (i <= to)
            {
                int square = i * i;
                sum += square;
                i++;
            }

            long int where_am_i = ftell(aux);
            printf("I am process %i writing %i on byte: %li\n", process_count, sum, where_am_i);

            fwrite(&sum, sizeof(int), 1, aux);
            fclose(aux);
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            wait(&status);
            process_count++;
        }
    } while (process_count < np);

    FILE *aux;
    aux = fopen("./parciais.txt", "r");

    int sum;
    for (int i = 0; i <= np - 1; i++)
    {

        fseek(aux, sizeof(int) * i, SEEK_SET);
        long int where_am_i = ftell(aux);

        int read;
        fread(&read, sizeof(int), 1, aux);
        printf("I am reading %i at byte: %li\n", read, where_am_i);

        sum += read;
    }
}
```

I expected the output to be something such as:

```
I am process 0 writing 98021 on byte: 0
I am process 1 writing 677369 on byte: 4
I am process 2 writing 1911310 on byte: 8
I am reading 98021 at byte: 0
I am reading 677369 at byte: 4
I am reading 1911310 at byte: 8
```

But I get:

```
I am process 0 writing 98021 on byte: 0
I am process 1 writing 677369 on byte: 4
I am process 2 writing 1911310 on byte: 8
I am reading 0 at byte: 0
I am reading 0 at byte: 4
I am reading 1911310 at byte: 8
```

This means, for some reason, only the last value is written.

I've been banging my head on the wall over this and I just can't find where's the catch... Can someone please lend me a hand?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi! I managed to scrub some lines from my code but I think this is really the minimum I can get...

Comment: Output is buffered in the process, not immediately written to disk (or disk cache).  If you want other processes to se the data, then use `fflush`

Comment: Ok, thanks! But where exactly should I put the fflush?

Comment: I don't think it's a flushing problem, since you `fclose()` immediately after your `fwrite()`s, and closing also flushes.

Comment: What are `n` and `np`?

Comment: @JoséPedroSousa The question has been answered nicely, but still, when we ask for a MCVE is because people don't like to guess what the variables/function you're using mean. Your code should be ready to copy and paste in an IDE, compile and run. In your case, for example, n and np are undefined.

Comment: Oh, I'm very much sorry... I really intended to decrease as much as possible the amount of code, but really forgot to specify the values of n and np. They could be, for example, n = 660 and np = 4. The purpose of the program is to create np processes, each one summing the square of the n/np numbers and then sum them all at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to `fopen("./parciais.txt", "w")` :
"w" : "Creates an empty file for writing. If a file with the same name already exists, its content is erased and the file is considered as a new empty file."
<s>Try with "a" instead!</s>
("Appends to a file. Writing operations, append data at the end of the file. The file is created if it does not exist.")

As mentioned in another answer, the "a" argument is not enough either. The file must be created once, hence in the main process, and then accessed in "r+b" mode for the fseek to work correctly!

Comment: Yes, the problem is likely the open mode.  No, append mode is not the answer, as it always writes at the *end* of the file, not the current position.  To open a binary file without truncating, and also to allow writing other than at (current) end-of-file, the needed mode would be `"r+b"` or, equivalently, `"rb+"`.  The `b` can be omitted on Linux, and I think on *any* current platform that supports `fork()`, but it makes a difference on some other platforms, such as Windows.

Comment: Even with his fseek() just after opening the file?

Comment: Thank you very much you both! It worked perfectly just by changing "w" to "r+" since I'm on POSIX (mac) and it is meant to be run on a Linux machine. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, @B.Go.  That is key characteristic of the append modes: writes *always* go to the end of the file (they are appended) regardless of the file offset immediately prior to the write.

Answer (score 1):

As @B.Go already answered, the main problem is that you are opening the file with mode `"w"`, which truncates it to zero length if it already exists.  Each child process does this, clobbering the contents written by the previous one.

You want this combination of behaviors for the file:

- it is created if it does not already exist (or I suppose you want this, at least)
- it is *not* truncated upon opening if it *does* already exist
- you may write to it
- writes start at the current file offset, as opposed to automatically going to the current end of the file
- the file is binary, not subject to any kind of character translation or to tail truncation upon writing to it

Unfortunately, there is no standard mode that provides all of it: the various `r` modes require that the file already exist, the `w` modes truncate the file if it does already exist, and the `a` modes direct all writes to the current end of the file, regardless of the stream's current offset.  If you can assume that the file will already exist then mode `"r+b"`, which can also be spelled `"rb+"`, has all the wanted characteristics except creating the file if it doesn't exist:

```
    aux = fopen("./parciais.txt", "r+b");
```

That permits reading as well, but just because you *can* read from the file doesn't mean you have to do.  Additionally, on Linux and POSIX-conforming systems, there is no distinction between binary and text files, so you can omit the `b` if you are confident that your program needs to run only on POSIX systems.  That you are using `fork()` suggests that this condition may apply to you.

If you must provide for creating the file, too, then open it once at the very beginning of the program, using any of the `w` or `a` modes depending on whether you want to truncate the file, then immediately close it again:

```
FILE *aux = fopen("./parciais.txt", "a");
if (aux) {
    fclose(aux);
} else {
    // handle error ...
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! I really didn't read the "it overwrites the current file" in the documentation. A small error that makes a huge difference. Thank you very much!